Find line of intersection of a pair of perpendicular tangent planes to the ellipsoid
We are given that a pair of perpendicular tangent planes to the ellipsoid
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
passes through the fixed point $(0,0,k)$. Show that the line of intersection of the planes lies on the cone
$$x^2(b^2+c^2-k^2)+y^2(a^2+c^2-k^2)+(z-k)^2(a^2+b^2)=0$$
My Attempt:
I took the envelope cone of the ellipsoid from the vertex $(0,0,k)$. This gave me
$$\frac{x^2(k^2-c^2)}{a^2}+\frac{y^2(k^2-c^2)}{b^2} = (z-k)^2$$
How do I proceed from here? I tried to take two general points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, form two tangential planes and take their line of intersection but I am not able to eliminate the two points.
